# video playlist to rtmp server seamless playback using ffmpeg without re-encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp, playlist

I have a list of rtmp compatible videos that make up a continuous playlist.

I've run into the common problem, that if I try to stream each one sequentially using separate ffmpeg commands, there is a significant gap that occurs on the streaming service.

I not only want to eliminate this gap, but also adapt the ffmpeg output to playlist updates if it's edited on the fly, much like how a playlist system works in any media player, as well as a basic seeking mechanism.

By what method is this possible?

Also - I know I'm asking a lot in one question, and I suspect the answer is a definitive 'no' - but I'd like to know if it is possible to use different resolutions and/or frame rates without stopping and starting the rtmp stream.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to know if it is possible to use different resolutions and/or
>   frame rates without stopping and starting the rtmp stream.

This is outside the RTMP specification. It is POSSIBLE to build a sever to support it, but of the hundreds of existing server implementations in existence, its unlikely that many do.